# Customize intent in share button with splitting string or how to split string and replace odd commas

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, share

Description: I want to use share button. With share button user sending a list as a message. In the list each item has Title + Description
The problem: System get all items from a list and put it in the line one after another by using a comma.

I have: TitleItemOne,DescriptionItemOne,TitleItemTwo,DescriptionItemTwo

I need:
 
TitleItemOne - DescriptionItemOne 
TitleItemTwo - DescriptionItemTwo

Or:
Maybe it is easier to replace all ODD comma "," with "-" so it will that style which i am looking for.

That's the code (needed code in Sharebutton method)

```
/**
 * Displays list of list that were entered and stored in the app.
 */
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";

    /** Identifier for the pet data loader */
    private static final int LIST_LOADER = 0;

    /** Adapter for the ListView */
    ListCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        Log.v(TAG, "Зашли в catalog activity oncreate");

        // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Find the ListView which will be populated with the list data
        ListView listListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        listListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        // Setup an Adapter to create a list item for each row of list data in the Cursor.
        // There is no items data yet (until the loader finishes) so pass in null for the Cursor.
        mCursorAdapter = new ListCursorAdapter(this, null);
        listListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        // Setup the item click listener
        listListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                ShoppingListBdHelper helper = new ShoppingListBdHelper(view.getContext());
                if (helper.setCompleted(id)) {
                    mCursorAdapter.setCompleted(view);
                }
            }
        });

        // Kick off the loader
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LIST_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_catalog.xml file.
        // This adds menu items to the app bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to a click on the "Insert dummy data" menu option
            case R.id.action_share_button:
                shareButton(mCursorAdapter.getCursor());
                return true;
            // Respond to a click on the "Delete all entries" menu option
            case R.id.action_delete_all_entries:
                deleteAllItems();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Share button
     */
    private void shareButton(Cursor cursor) {

        Log.v(TAG, "--- WE ARE IN SHARE BUTTON METHOD ---");

        List<String> test;
        test = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "field: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME)));

            test.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME))); //add the item
            test.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION))); //add the item
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        Log.v(TAG, "--- OUR LIST INCLUDES: " + test.toString());

        Intent myIntent = new Intent();
        myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<String>) test);
        myIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, test.toString());

        Log.v(TAG, "--- INTENT EXTRAS ARE: " + myIntent.getExtras());

        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share using"));
    }


    /**
     * Helper method to delete all list in the database.
     */
    private void deleteAllItems() {

        Log.v(TAG, "Сработал метод удаления всех данных");
        long rowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(ListContract.ListEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
        Log.v("CatalogActivity", rowsDeleted + " rows deleted from list database");
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Начал работать loader cursor");
        // Define a projection that specifies the columns from the table we care about.
        String[] projection = {
                ListContract.ListEntry._ID,
                ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME,
                ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
                ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_COMPLETED
        };

        // This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
        return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
                ListContract.ListEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
                projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                null,                   // No selection clause
                null,                   // No selection arguments
                null);                  // Default sort order

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Update {@link ListCursorAdapter} with this new cursor containing updated pet data
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        Log.v(TAG, "Cursor adapter загрузился");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // Callback called when the data needs to be deleted
        mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have t1,d1,t2,d2,t3... with in one index of the list? and you want t1-d1 in the same list entry?

Comment: @TonyKutzler i want to know how i can customize it. Make t1-d1 </br> t2-d2 ... For example... On the step when the list inside another app like text message it goes only t1,d1,t2,d2

Comment: @TonyKutzler I have found something what i am looking for. I can split string and replace all 1,3,5 commas with "-". So the list will looks as i want. But i dont know how to replace only ODD commas

Comment: Just add t1-d1 to list then add t2-... and so on

Comment: @TonyKutzler i can't get it. I can add "-" but it make t1-,d1, Its not replace it. Its just add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`test.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME))); //add the item test.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION)));`

To

`test.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME)) + "-" + (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListContract.ListEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_DESCRIPTION)));`

Note:
I may not have all the parenthesis correctly closed, but you get the idea

Comment: Thank you Mister Tony. I knew that it has to be easier way. And this is it. you are pro)

Comment: I saw this last night, however your question was worded funny, your welcome.

Answer (score 2):

you can format your **strings** to **html** or using `"\n"`

string to html :

you can use `Html.fromHtml()` to use HTML tag in your string :

```
Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

for using `"\n"` you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` wich is OS dependent line separator

Comment: Could you please give me the example based on my code?

Comment: I have found something what i am looking for. I can split string and replace all 1,3,5 commas with "-". So the list will looks as i want. But i dont know how to replace only ODD commas